# How to change the size of a plot in an Enterprise Guide report

Tags: plot, sas, enterprise-guide

I create a scatter plot in EG-project outputting it into standard EG report output destination (not sure, how to call it correctly?). The scatter plot is a bit crowded along y-axis, so I'd like to stretch it vertically. I tried to change `goptions vsize=` and `goptions ypixels=`, but it doesn't make any changes in the plot appearance. Would appreciate any help with that!

I run SAS 9.3 (TS1M0) and EG 4.3.

Comment: What version of SAS are you running - 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, or an older one?

Comment: Added it to the question

Comment: Thanks.  Also, can you see the code behind the plot?  Is it running PROC GPLOT or PROC SGPLOT or PROC SGSCATTER?

Comment: Actually, I use my code (not built-in task), and it's SGPLOT with SCATTER statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GOPTIONS` is used for SAS/GRAPH, while `ODS GRAPHICS` is used for ODS Graphics (any of the `SG*` procedures, plus anything like `PROC UNIVARIATE` when `ODS GRAPHICS` is turned on).

```
ods graphics height=<height>;
```

would be how you change the height.

See the [ODS Graphics Tip Sheet](http://support.sas.com/rnd/app/ODSGraphics/TipSheet_ODSGraphics.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joe! I'm always confused with all this graphics and ODS stuff. Time to roll up my sleeves and start to learn it:)

Comment: Indeed - SG* are wonderful procedures, far better than SAS/GRAPH, and GTL (graph template language) is even better, if you're on 9.3 or 9.4.